# T= 2x2 matrix with inputs [5/4 -1/4] and [3/4 1/4] across. Set xn=T^n (1,0) for n >=1.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $T= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{5}{4} &  -\frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4}\end{bmatrix}$. Set $x_n=T^n \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ for $n\geq 1$. Need to prove that $(x_n)$ converges and find the limit $y$. Also have to find an explicit $N$ so that $\left\|x_n-y\right\| < (1/2)10^{-100}$ for all $n \geq N$. I am not sure how to solve this question at all. I know that to find an explicit $N$, we can use induction but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Have you tried diagonalizing it?

Comment: yes. it is not diagonalizable

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot a step!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [diagonalizes](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B5%2F4%2C+-1%2F4%7D%2C%7B3%2F4%2C1%2F4%7D%7D) to

$$ T = SJS^{-1} = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\ 1 & 1}\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\pmatrix{-\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}} .$$

Noting that $T^n = SJ^nS^{-1}$ we then have 
$$x_n = \pmatrix{\frac{1}{3} & 1 \\ 1 & 1}\pmatrix{(\frac{1}{2})^n & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\pmatrix{-\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}}\pmatrix{1 \\ 0}.$$

Multiplying $x_n$ out we have

$$ x_n = \pmatrix{-2^{-(n + 1)} + \frac{3}{2} \\ -3\cdot2^{-(n+1)} + \frac{3}{2}}. $$

Thus, noting that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \pmatrix{\frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2}}$, we know

$$|| x_n - p || = || \pmatrix{-2^{-(n + 1)} & -3\cdot2^{-(n+1)}}^T || = 2^{-(n - 1)} < \frac{1}{2}10^{-100},$$

assuming that the norm is just the max of the sum of the absolute values of each column. If you are using a different definition of the norm, then change as required.

Using this we now have

$$2^{-(n - 1)} < \frac{1}{2}10^{-100} \iff \ln{2^{-n + 2}} < \ln{10^{-100}} \iff -n < \frac{\ln{10^{-100}}}{\ln 2} - 2 \iff n > -\frac{\ln{10^{-100}}}{\ln 2} + 2.$$

Comment: So from that, do I simplify to find what xn= and that is the limit?

Comment: Yeah, if you take the limit what happens to that $1/2^n$ term?

Comment: well it becomes (1/2^n 0) (except top down- I do not know how to put in proper form)

Comment: It converges to zero. So all that is left is multiplying out the matrices and then after doing so solve for the value of n that gives our desired error.

Comment: Question, does $\left\|x_n-y\right\|$ stand for the matrix norm?

Comment: Answer, Yes it does

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll update my answer for analysis of that part of the question.